# How to override method of an instance in rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, singleton

In our rails 3.2.12 app, we want to `override method` for an `instance` and make it return empty. Ideally we can define ONE `generic overriding method` for each and every `model` in the app.

For example, `@project` is an instance of the `Project` model and `phone` is a column name. After method override, we want `@project.phone` to return empty at run time instead of the value of the column. If there is another model `customer` in the app, we can do `@customer.name` and receive nil assuming `@customer` is an `instance` of the `customer`.

We feel `singleton class` and `define_method` may help here. But we are not quite understand how they are going to work. Can someone shed some light on the issue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the phone number in the view, or are you trying to conceal from the business logic the fact that these instances have those particular attributes?

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to achieve that, but can you tell us why you need this functionality? Is it to prevent access to certain columns for certain users, for example?

Comment: Yes, we are going to use the method in views. The idea is not change anything in view and still use, for example, <%=@project.phone%> in view. When @project.phone is called, the override method is going to kick in and return empty if the user access rule says so. This is similar of hiding a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you only want to do this in views, then it strikes me that a view helper would be worth considering:

```
# view.html.haml
= value_for_view(:phone, @project)

# application_helper.rb
def value_for_view(attribute, object)
  if overide_attributes_in_view? && object.respond_to?("#{attribute}_for_view")
    object.send("#{attribute}_for_view")
  else
    object.send(attribute)
  end
end

# application.rb
def overide_attributes_in_view?
  #do your stuff here to determine whether the original values should be shown or the 'overloads'
end

# project.rb
def phone_for_view
  nil # just add methods called "attribute_for_view" for whatever attributes you want to whatever models you want to have the attributes 'overloaded' (it's not really overloading, but it serves the purpose you describe)
end
```

Or similarly... you could patch AR::Base to have a 'value_for_view' method, so the view would look more like this:

```
# view.html.haml
= @project.value_for_view(:phone)

# monkey_patch_file.rb
def value_for_view(attribute)
  if respond_to?("#{attribute}_for_view")
    send("#{attribute}_for_view")
  else
    send(attribute)
  end
end
```

If you insist on just being able to call @project.phone and get one or the other values, you'll need to pass @project a flag to tell it to do the calculations for you as Rovermicroer's answer shows (though, as I commented, I'm not sure 'super' will work, but the principle is correct).

Answer (score 3):

Ignore all this, the additional comment makes this worthless.

Instead of overwriting an instance method why not just have an instance variable that acts like a switch for the method.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def phone
    if @do_not_call
      nil
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def do_not_call
    @do_not_call = true
  end

  def do_call
    @do_not_call = false
  end

end
```

Your going to need something like CanCan

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Use can can to set abilities of users and do something like the following.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def phone
    if current_user can? :phone, self
      super
    else
      nil
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: The method is going to be used in view. The view is going to decide if the column should be blank or not based on the user access rule. The idea is not change anything in view.  For example, <%= @project.phone %> will return the phone# if the user has access to phone or blank if not based on user access rule.

Comment: Then instead of if @do_not_call, you could do something like if current_user && current_user.can_see_phone(this), where can_see_phone would be a method on user that would return true if the user has access to phone numbers on that project.

Comment: Since we don't know beforehead which field is going to be empty, unless we put a definitions for every field in the model. Is there a way we only need to define once and use it on all field?

Comment: I'm not sure 'super' will work, as AIUI, the attribute accessors are provided by method_missing. You would need "read_attribute[:phone]" instead (runs off to play with it to check though :-)

Comment: Oh.. and you've set an instance method at the class level (so nothing will ever access the '@do_not_call' that is set at the top, and it will just be nil by default until one of the do_ or do_not_call methods are called - probs best to just use an attr_accessor ;-)

Comment: Your right about screwing up and setting it on the class level, but super does work just tried it out myself. But the logic stays the same, but in this case there is really no difference between the behavior if its nil or false.

Comment: Yeah I forgot you can't override initialize either in a activerecord model, so I guess if your going to use a plane old instance variable in a model the logic will have to work with it starting out as nil.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of overriding a method of an object (instance) is the following:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
#@project.phone contains the database value

def @project.phone
  ""
end
#@project.phone returns an empty string now
```

Comment: Is there a way we can define the method once and call it by adding the object instance? There are many models in our app.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your problem. Can you try to rephrase it? As someone pointed out, adding methods to an instance is a rare technique. What would you like to achieve from the user perspective?

Comment: We need to add some intelligence to rails view so that it know returning empty when access rules says so.